# How do I keep Geany's versions updated after installing it in my system?

Tags: repository, geany

When will Geany 0.21 be in the repos, instead of Geany 0.20? Whose responsibility is it, Ubuntu or Geany?

I wasn't sure of where I could get packages information, so I just used Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What's new in 0.21? Btw I wonder when they'll release a GTK3 version - the lack of smooth-scrolling can be a bit annoying.

Answer (score 30):

After the release of an Ubuntu version packages are only updated for security and big fixes. No further release is done for individual packages.

If you want to keep Geany up to date you need to add a PPA. Luckily Geany keeps a developers PPA that has the version you are looking for.

Install it by using these commands on a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geany-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.10 | Lubuntu 16.10 and or higher version you can use this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install geany-plugins.
```

After installation you can go to
    ✓ Tools => Plugins Manager
Then you can set it up for your individual needs.

Answer (score -1):

No Need of PPA , you can directly install it by using below command from the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install geany geany-common
```

The current stable release is more than the mentioned version. If you are asking about the latest update then : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany here you can check the latest version.

```
kmcet@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache policy geany
geany:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.23.1+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.23.1+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
kmcet@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: This the question should be "how do I keep it updated", no specific about the actual version of Geany. If the version present in saucy is obsolete you will need a PPA to update it to a newer version. The PPA in my answer is the official PPA for debs releases from Geany.